# Does flipping the kernel in image processing only help maintain mathematical symmetry?

Tags: image-processing, kernel-functions

So I've been really confused about the act of flipping a kernel in image processing. Is there any intuitive way to think about it or does it only help computing efficiently and maintain the mathematical symmetry? 
Do we necessarily flip a kernel in image processing? (say the kernel is not symmetrical). Do we only flip it because we'll put it in a convolution later?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Virtually all kernels used in image processing are symmetric or antisymmetric, and we don't really care about the flipping.

Answer (score 1):

Flipping the kernel comes from the pure-math context of a convolution, where it is a natural thing to do. See this part of [3b1b's video](https://youtu.be/KuXjwB4LzSA?t=807) on convolutions where he gives a great intuitive answer to your question.